# Create Custom Function to return random cell value from a range

Tags: excel, vba, function, random

I am a VBA amateur and am trying to create a custom function that returns a random value from a known range. I must be doing something wrong with the following code because it causes the program to crash.

Do you have any idea how I can make the corrections that will allow the function to loop through each cell of the range until the cell value equals the random number, which has been arbitrarily bound by 1 and 1000?

Thanks so much for any thoughts!

```
Function RandinList(InRange As Range) As Long

Dim random As Long
Dim cell As Range

Do

    random = Int((1000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

    For Each cell In InRange
        If Not random = cell Then Exit For
    Next cell

Loop Until cell.Value = random

RandinList = random

End Function
```

Comment: Why loop if you know the random number?

Comment: The intent is to randomly select a number from a range.

Comment: In other words, you're not doing anything with `cell.Value` in your snippet.

Comment: You're right. Would the following be an appropriate way to end the Loop? 

Loop Until Cell Is Random

Comment: I don't think you need to loop here at all actually.

Comment: I guess my initial inclination was to loop through the range of values and test each cell to determine if it was equal to the randomly generated number and exit the loop if that condition was met. 

Would you instead just apply the Rnd function to the range?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the intention of your function isn't discernible. Therefore I have modified that intention. The function below will not return both the random number itself and the location in `InRange` where it was found. Here is the function.

```
Function RandInList(InRange As Range) As Long

    Dim Random As Long
    Dim Fnd As Range

    Random = Int((1000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Set Fnd = InRange.Find(Random, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The generated random number " & Random & vbCr & _
               "wasn't found in the given range.", _
               vbInformation, "Number not found"
    Else
        Set InRange = Fnd
    End If
    RandInList = Random
End Function
```

As you see, I didn't pick up on your idea to loop through the cells. Looking at 1000 cells will cause a noticeable delay. `Find` is instantaneous.

I used the following code to test my function.

```
Private Sub TestRandInList()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A2:G20")
    Debug.Print RandInList(Rng), Rng.Address
End Sub
```

As you see, it first sets `Set Rng = Range("A2:G20")` and then asks for `Rng.Address` after the function call. In fact, the address may have been changed in the function, here: `Set InRange = Fnd`. So, if `Random` was found it contains the cell address. On the other hand, if it wasn't found the address of `Rng` remains unchanged. In your calling procedure you can test for success like this: `If Rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then` the cell was found. This is because if the range wasn't change it will have many more cells than 1.

Of course, the function returns the value of the random number that was generated as well.